# Does bootstrap-4 need Html5shiv?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using `bootstrap 4` for my projects.

As before using the bootstrap i used **`html5shiv`** cause it was needed to provide ***compatibility*** for *`IE Browsers older than IE 9`*. Otherwise html5 elements won't support as you all know. 
So, my question do we need to declare the **`html5shiv`**  along with new `bootstrap 4` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to declare html5shiv in Bootstrap 4. Here's what the basic HTML template for Bootstrap 4 looks like:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, while Internet Explorer 10+ is supported in Bootstrap 4, IE9 and down is not. More about supported devices:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Comment: Isn't  this the reason why developer use html5shiv to support their html5 tag styling in ie9 or older version?

Comment: and whyy use popper.min.js?  isnit it tether.min.js?

Comment: This isn't really a place for philosophical discussions. You asked a question, I answered it. Bootstrap clearly states on their website that if you need to support IE9 or older, you should use Bootstrap 3. So, it's them who made that decision, not me.

Comment: The most recent version of Bootstrap 4 (which is beta 3) is using popper.js instead of tether.js. It doesn't really matter why. This is just something they decided to do. We have to use that if we want to use Bootstrap 4. The next version of Bootstrap 4 will be the final release and they aren't gonna introduce any breaking changes there. So, it will be popper.js from now on.

Comment: I didn't ask you why they did something.